# how do you copy files from Azure file shares to Azure Blob?

Tags: azure

I need to copy files from Azure file share to Azure Blob, i tried using storage explorer but cant seem to see where you can do this, is there a way of copying files from azure files to azure blob storage?

Comment: From Azure Storage perspective, it is entirely possible to do so however I am surprised to see that this feature is missing in Microsoft Storage Explorer (I just tried it in version 1.20.1). You may want to try `azcopy` to accomplish this. If you are looking for a UI tool, please check out [`Cerebrata`](https://www.cerebrata.com). It is a commercial tool (thus not free) that has this functionality. Disclosure - I am part of the team that built this tool.

Comment: do you know the az copy command to do this?

Comment: I believe it is azcopy copy but please check out the documentation. You’ll find examples of the same there.

Comment: i did but they didnt work hence the question in here

Comment: Please edit your question and include the azcopy command you tried.